# Is it possible for Visual Studio to use default colors when pasting into other applications (eg. Outlook)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, outlook, syntax-highlighting, visual-styles

I have a custom color theme within visual studio which uses a dark background which looks great, however when I copy & paste into Outlook I would like outlook to use the default formatting, is this possible?

My current workaround is to simply paste into a single cell table, reset the background color on the text to none and apply a background color to the table cell.

Any ideas on a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of outlook you are using but in 2007 I think that changing your cut and past options in advance editor options will do the trick.
take a look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA102087481033.aspx#2

Marcus